# conditional statment to display all entries that are from today and forward

Tags: conditionals, date

Have

- events channel
- have 10 entries
- have a date field called event_start_date

Desire
 - display only up coming events in asc order

List

- 2016-12-06
- 2016-11-01
- 2016-10-24
- 2016-05-30
- 2016-09-12
- 2016-05-15
- 2016-05-02
- 2016-03-29
- 2016-03-01
- 2016-02-08

Code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" orderby="event_start_date" sort="asc"}
  {if {event_start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'} >= {current_time format='%Y-%m-%d'}}
    {event_start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}<br>
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Results:

```
2016-02-08
2016-03-01
2016-03-29
2016-05-02
2016-05-15
2016-05-30
2016-09-12
2016-10-24
2016-11-01
2016-12-06
```

Desired

```
2016-05-15
2016-05-30
2016-09-12
2016-10-24
2016-11-01
2016-12-06
```

What am i doing wrong?

Final working code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" orderby="event_start_date" sort="asc" search:event_start_date=">={current_time}"}
    {event_start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}<br>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the search parameter - https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name

```
search:event_start_date=">={current_time}"
```

How are you storing your date field? unix, mysql??

Comment: thanks! that search on was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler if you were to use the EE default `{entry_date}` that way you could use `start_on=` with `show_future_entries="yes"`:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" start_on="{current_time}" orderby="date" show_future_entries="yes"}
...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on)

Your current use of a custom field will return, lets say 30 entries and then you'll subsequently have to query, each of those 30 entries, one at a time, if this fields value is greater then the current date - all of which is an expensive DB/EE operation.

**PS.** Your conditional, is trying to compare a string that includes operators it should be just numbers. Try removing the `format=` part from your tag.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Unfortunately using the entry date doesn't work in this scenario since it's an upcoming dates scenario.  it would require people to modify 2 fields rather than just one.

Comment: Yet if you remove the custom date field and stick with the standard entry_date field - users will only alter one field. Just code your templates with `show_future_entries='yes'` and it's done.